# Why was this question, which seemed reasonable to me, deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I don't understand why this question was deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862597/c-modulus-operator

Could the powers that be please explain why this happened?

*Note 1*: Question has now been undeleted. It had two delete votes and then received a delete vote from a mod (Robert Harvey). Then it was very shortly afterwards undeleted by that same mod.

*Note 2*: Now it has been deleted with the final delete vote from another diamond mod (Tim Post).

Comment: Closed is not the same as deleted...

Comment: @Lix Yes, I know. It was deleted at the point at which I asked the question.

Comment: @Lix post was [undeleted](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9862597/revisions) by Robert Harvey♦

Comment: I'd be interested to understand why Robert deleted and then undeleted. I guess that clears delete vote count and means that of the first two delete voters cannot cast more delete votes.

Comment: Correct correct and correct my friends - but the OP says deleted which the question is not.  Helpful information to anyone else viewing this thread and any other "Why was this question 'deleted'" posts..

Comment: I also have to say that the downvoting on meta is just ridiculous. Aren't I meant to come here to ask these questions? Where else should I go?

Comment: Delete votes racking up again already. Looks like @Lix's comments will shortly be overtaken by events.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why ridiculous? downvoting occurs when there is a people who disagree with you or just think this (I don't mean literally this) is stupid or badly asked question

Comment: There's more going on with this user: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9861282/17034

Comment: @om-nom-nom What is there in my question that can be disagreed with? I simply asked for clarification and was seeking understanding.

Comment: @David Heffernan: "What is there that can be disagreed with?" Some people think that question sucks and should have stayed deleted. I dunno. Downvotes are all opinionated here, and that's a harsh reality of meta.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Meta works differently than SO. Votes have a different meaning here. They merely signal accord/discord.

Comment: Clearly I don't understand meta yet. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: That's not a question. That's 4 questions. 4 questions the user could have answered by compiling and running the code. If the outcome of the compilation and/or running did not make sense, then *that* would have been something that could have been a question. The question, as asked, sucks. It was closed. There's no reason to keep it around. Delete it.

Comment: @Uphill Luge, David (and other 10k users): May very well be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861683/please-vote-this-down-so-i-can-win-a-badge

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Not all the questions could have been answered by running code. Question 2 could not have been answered that way.

Comment: @BoltClock OK, it seems that xtrm0 has racked up some hate here and I've come to the party late.

Comment: @David: Racked up some hate? Here's only been a member for **today** and look what he's causing.

Comment: Hmm, lots of non-C++ programmers here seem to miss that there's a lot more to subtlety to certain C++ questions than can be captured by simply "did it compile?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think all the animosity is based on how he's been [trying to game the Peer Pressure badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861683/please-vote-this-down-so-i-can-win-a-badge) (deleted, viewable by 10k users only). The community probably thinks this is yet another of his lame attempts to try and get the badge, and so is treating it very harshly.

The others have voiced their opinions here on how this question should have been closed and deleted, and I'll simply say that I agree that this question sucks and ought to have been deleted, which it now is. But indeed, there was more to this whole thing than meets the eye, and I'm sure the aforementioned behavior had to do with it.

Oh, the poor sod, that xtrm0.

Comment: "...probably thinks..." - Just from the title of that deleted post I can also say *probably* wanted to win a badge... People should have upvoted so he would have some **scarlet** rep... :P

Comment: @Lix: `ALTER TABLE Users ADD Notoriety INT NOT NULL;`

Comment: To be implemented immediately!  Runs to post a feature-request that was rejected before I could finish typing this comment. ;) It could be like good vs bad rep - instead of one number you'd have two :P

Answer (score 8):

Based on the comments below the question, what the OP seems to want is a comprehensive answer about the behavior of all of his examples in every possible compiler.  That's not really what we do here; Stack Overflow is not a free research service.

Users are expected to show some effort; if the OP really wants to know the answer to the question posed in their comment, the best way they can do that is to read up on the language specification, and try out their examples on their own, using a couple of compilers.

In the case of this particular user, there may be some suspicion of trolling; he posted a question titled *"Please downvote this so that I can get a peer pressure badge,"* and another one titled *"Please solve my homework for me."*  The community is not stupid; they realize that they can easily perma-ban a user at the IP level by casting a lot of downvotes and deleting the question, and they don't even need a mod to do it.

Comment: So why did you delete and then undelete?

Comment: The comment you refer to in your first sentence was this "I want to check if it works on all the compilers, not just on my pc." I could take that to mean that xtrm0 did not want to rely on trial and error. See the subsequent discussion between me and kerreck. I don't buy the "read the language specification" argument. Are you saying we should vote to close and delete questions if the answer can be found in the language specs?

Comment: Are you really advocating that someone should break out a bunch of compilers, and test all of the OP's examples on each one?  Even if you believe that such a question could be answered by experienced people just by looking at the code, it's a slippery slope; in my experience, the OP will continue to ask trivial questions about every little syntax error they encounter.

Comment: That's not at all what I mean. But I just took that comment to mean that xtrm0 knows that running code on one compiler with one set of inputs does not prove it does the same for all compilers and all possible inputs. And yes, any experienced C++ programmer answers that Q in their sleep without resort to a compiler. We get questions like this all the time that don't get close votes. I'm sure it's personal. Note that the answer got 4 upvotes. That doesn't happen when you answer a totally idiotic question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: There's really not much that I as moderator can do about that kind of community sentiment, unless you really feel the OP is being treated unfairly.  I won't undelete the question; it doesn't rise to a sufficient level of quality.

Comment: `Note that the answer got 4 upvotes. That doesn't happen when you answer a totally idiotic question.` -- It happens often enough that we created a badge for it: Reversal.

Comment: I don't want the question to be undeleted. I never said that. I fully respect the community view. I just wanted to understand why such an innocuous question got so much hate. Now I know to avoid xtrm0.

Comment: Reversal, a badge awarded 98 times   ;-)

Comment: I assume you know about the question he posted titled *"Please downvote this so I can get a Peer Pressure badge,"* and the question he posted titled *"Please solve my homework for me"?*  Also, I didn't say it was *easy* to get a reversal badge. :)

Comment: Really, don't get me wrong, I'm just looking to understand what I thought was a strange and unexpected reaction on this Q.

Comment: When I answered, I did not know about those questions. So, it all seems about enmity. If someone wrote that in an answer, I'd accept it!! Gah, an undeletion and  16 more upvotes and I could have been no. 99!  Thanks for your time on this and thanks as always for the great work you put in on the site.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Done.

Comment: Is that right? If a user gets enough downvotes and deletes, then they get an IP ban?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to start off by stating that I do not know C++ and my opinions here are from my personal experience on SO.  If there are other underlying technical problems with the post - you will not find them in my answer.

---

The problem here really is that there is no real question here.
You asked "will I get any errors?"

- Did you try solve your issue before you posted?
- Did you do any research?

Asking if an error will occur is not a good type of question to ask on SO (as you have learnt by the closing of your question).
You'll need to give more information

- What is it that you are trying to accomplish?
- Where in your code does this line appear?
- What is the desired behavior?
- What is the actual behavior?

The question is very vague and does not meet the high standards that are required by the site's current population.

To put it more simply - your post could have been answered in one word - and you would not have liked it -
The answer would have been -

## `possibly`

---

You **did** get an answer though - and by your comments it seems helpful - cheer up and take this lesson with you to your next post on SO.

Comment: Well, I do know a bit about C++ and in my view the question was precise and could answered precisely. I think there is something else at play with this user. As for your final paragraph, I provided the answer, not asked the question.

Comment: @Dav - no disrespect meant - but do you *really* believe that this is a good question for the SO format?

Comment: Vast numbers of questions that are a lot worse than this don't get closed. Even greater numbers of poorer questions don't get deletde. I just wanted to understand what was happening here. Having heard more comments, I don't think it has anything to do with the question and is all about the enemies that xtrm0 has made.

Comment: (I agree with Lix, though indeed there [is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861197/infinite-recursion-c/9861282#9861282) *also* [something else at play](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qMmf2.png), @David. I am not sure what though. As an aside, Lix, it's not the OP who has asked this Meta question.)

Comment: @Dav - the fact that people don't close/delete ALL the problematic posts is not an indication that they should be allowed.  But here again I am entering an area outside of my expertise - I'll leave that decision to you guys :)  And yes - it seems there is mischief afoot...

Comment: (The question asker was attempting to game the Peer Pressure badge, got quite a negative backlash at the (at least) second attempt to do so by posting a ridiculous question.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That some questions never get closed just means that they are not interesting enough to the community to get the necessary number of views and votes for closure.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, and my question was to try and understand what was so special about this particular question that meant it received so much attention.